# Securing Client ID and Client Secret in OAuth2

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I am really confused about how to secure Client ID and Client Secret in client-app within OAuth2. Some articles i found suggested to implement proxy-oauth that sits between client-app and OAuth2 server. With the existence of proxy-oauth, client-app doesn't need to store client id and client secret, instead it will make a call to request token to proxy-oauth then the proxy-oauth will make a call to request token to the real OAuth2 server using client ID and client secret that are stored in proxy-oauth.

My question is what stop others make a call to request token to proxy-oauth? I mean, how do i identify that the request really come from my client app?